# models.py with ManyToMany and progmatically adding data via a shell script

Tags: django, django-models

First post to stackoverflow I did do a search and came up dry.  I also own 
the django book (Forcier,Bissex,Chun) and they don't explain how to do 
this.  In short I can't figure out how to progmatically add a data via 
a python shell script to the ManyToMay model..

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin

class Client(models.Model):
  client        = models.CharField(max_length=256, primary_key=True)
  access        = models.DateField()
  description   = models.TextField()
  host          = models.CharField(max_length=256)
  lineEnd       = models.CharField(max_length=256)
  options       = models.TextField()
  owner         = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  root          = models.CharField(max_length=256)
  submitOptions = models.CharField(max_length=256)
  update        = models.DateField()
  def __unicode__(self):
    return str(self.client)
admin.site.register(Client)


class Change(models.Model):
  """This simply expands out 'p4 describe' """
  change        = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
  client        = models.ManyToManyField(Client)
  desc          = models.TextField()
  status        = models.CharField(max_length=128)
  def __unicode__(self):
    return str(self.change)
admin.site.register(Change)
```

Here is what I have which works but I don't know how to add the 
ManyToMany.  I can't seem to figure out how to progmatically call it. 
I know the row in SQL exists.

---  massImport.py ---

```
# Assume the client "clientspec" exists.  I know how to create that if 
neeeded. 
changes = [ { 'change': 123, 'desc': "foobar", status': "foobar", 
client': "clientspec", }] 
for item in changes: 
  entry = Change( 
            change    = item['change'], 
            desc    = item['desc'], 
            status    = item['status'], 
            # client    = Client.objects.filter(client=item['client']) 
            ) 
  entry.save()
```

Can anyone show me where the error of my ways is.  I would really 
appreciate it. 
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.filter` returns a list, when you need is a single object, so you should use `.get(client=item['client'])`

Comment: Nope!!

TypeError: 'client' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Bummer - I thought you had it..

Answer (score 2):

Turns out Tiago was very close..

```
# Assume the client "clientspec" exists.  I know how to create that if 
neeeded. 
changes = [ { 'change': 123, 'desc': "foobar", status': "foobar", 
client': "clientspec", }] 
for item in changes: 
  entry = Change()
  entry.change  = item['change']
  entry.desc    = item['desc']
  entry.status  = item['status']
  entry.time    = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(float(item['time']))
  entry.client.add(Client.objects.get(client=item['client']))
  entry.save()
```

So.. I will give props to Tiago

Comment: +1 for `changes = [ { 'change': 123, 'desc': "foobar", status': "foobar", 
client': "clientspec", }]`  i usually use `changes=((123,'foobar','foobar','clientspec'),...)` looks very bad.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the code but i got error

`ValueError: "<Change: 123 -- foobar>" needs to have a value for field "change" before this many-to-many relationship can be used`

Manytomany(`entry.client.add`) can be used only after saving the field ie `entry.save()`

There may be a lot of clients so you can use:

```
changes = [{'change': 123, 'desc': "foobar", 'status': "foobar", 
'client': ("client1","client2"),},{......] 
for item in changes: 
    entry = Change( 
        change    = item['change'], 
        desc    = item['desc'], 
        status    = item['status'],)
    entry.save()
    for c in item['client']:
        entry.client.add(Client.objects.get(client=c))
```